# Sqoop Import as-parquetfile based on column value

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, parquet, partition

So I am trying to run a sqoop import job where I save the parquet files based on my partition_key. Ultimately I would like for my folder `/TABLE_DIR/`to have 5 parquet files, 1 for each unique partition key. Currently I only get 4. I cant set the num-mappers 5. Table2 the partition_key might go up to 8 and for that I want to get 8 parquet files etc etc.

```
Table1:
primary_key:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
partition_key: [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5]
value: [15,12,18,18,21,23,25,26,24,10]

Code:
sqoop import \
     --query "select primary_key,partition_key,value from Table1" \
     --compress --compression-codec snappy \
     --split-by partition_key \
     --target-dir /TABLE_DIR/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sqoop import is a map only job you cannot control number of output files . It will be taken care of by hadoop split mechanism(you could control this in mapreduce or pig ,hive scripts not sure about sqoop though ."fetch_size" parameter can be looked into though). However , if you really wanted to do the below

1. You could expose a hive table on this data(careful with the metadata file!).
2. Insert this data into another hive table(this too parquet) and while inserting do a sort by on any column(this is done to convert the insert-select,which will be a map only job again, to a map-reduce job) and set mapreduce.job.reduces to 5 or any desired value.

The property will force five reducers giving 5 output files.